# How do I group by in R where some rows (that are subsets of others) belong to multiple groups?

Tags: r, group-by, row, subset

Here's what my data looks like. I want rows to be grouped by date, ID1 and ID2. Rows that have  in ID3 get grouped into **all** rows they are a subset of, i.e., 1st and 2nd ID match. Also, statistics to be added up and n() to be generated.

```
      date     ID1     ID2     ID3 stat1 stat2 stat3
1 12-03-07  abc123  wxy456  pqr123    10    20     30  
2 12-03-07  abc123  wxy456  pqr123    20    40     60  
3 10-04-07  bcd456  wxy456  hgf356    10    20     40  
4 12-03-07  abc123  wxy456  hfz123    30    60     90  
5 12-03-07  abc123  wxy456   <NA>     40    50     70
```

Desired Output

```
date      ID1,     ID2,   ID3,   n, stat1, stat2, stat3  
12-03-07 abc123, wxy456, pqr123, 3,   70,   110, 160  
10-04-07 bcd456, wxy456, hgf356, 1,   10,   20,  40  
12-03-07 abc123, wxy456, hfz123, 2 ,  40,   50,  70
```

Comment: dplyr solution: `df %>% group_by(date, ID1, ID2, ID3) %>% summarise(n=n(), stat1=sum(stat1), stat2=sum(stat2), stat3=sum(stat3)`

Comment: that is similar to the solution I am working on. While that would take care of the grouping, it will group NA columns together, but not group them into all rows that have the same 1st and 2nd column but a different 3rd column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably more elegant solutions but solved this using dplyr's groupby/summarise  (as in Adam Quek's code)  by joining  and then computing average stats.

```
        # Summarize 
        df <- df %>% group_by(date, ID1, ID2, ID3) %>% summarise(n=n(), stat1=sum(stat1), stat2=sum(stat2), stat3=sum(stat3)

        # Select instances where NA
        dfNA <- df %>% filter(is.na(ID3))

        # Select instances where no NA
        df1 <- df %>% filter(!is.na(ID3))

        # Join these
        dfBig <- df1 %>% full_join(dfNA, by = c("date", "ID1")) %>% 
          subset(select= c("ID1", "date", "n.x", "n.y", "stat1.x", "stat1.y", "stat2.x", "stat2.y", "stat3.x", "stat3.y"))

        # Replace <NA>s by 0
        dfBig$stat1.x[is.na(dfBig$stat1.x)] <- 0
        dfBig$stat1.y[is.na(dfBig$stat1.y)] <- 0
        dfBig$stat2.x[is.na(dfBig$stat1.x)] <- 0
        dfBig$stat2.y[is.na(dfBig$stat1.y)] <- 0
        dfBig$stat3.x[is.na(dfBig$stat1.x)] <- 0
        dfBig$stat3.y[is.na(dfBig$stat1.y)] <- 0
        dfBig$n.x[is.na(dfBig$n.x)] <- 0
        dfBig$n.y[is.na(dfBig$n.y)] <- 0

    # Compute Mean stats and Rename Columns
        dfBig$stat1Mean <- (dfBig$stat1.x * dfBig$n.x + dfBig$stat1.y * dfBig$n.y) / (dfBig$n.x +dfBig$n.y)
        dfBig$stat2Mean <- (dfBig$stat1.x * dfBig$n.x + dfBig$stat1.y * dfBig$n.y) / (dfBig$n.x +dfBig$n.y)
        dfBig$stat3Mean <- (dfBig$stat1.x * dfBig$n.x + dfBig$stat1.y * dfBig$n.y) / (dfBig$n.x +dfBig$n.y)
        dfBig$n2 <- dfBig$n.x + dfBig$n.y
```